# How to comment script in Datamapper Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a XML to XML  mapping in DataMapper. Obviously soon after mapping done script will be present. How to I comment any line in script( Example here output.status line). 
 I have tried like this `//` but not seems to be commented.But could see by default Mule commented `//MEL`.

```
         //MEL
        //START -> DO NOT REMOVE
        output.__id = input.__id;
        //END -> DO NOT REMOVE
         output.vendorReference = input.Ref;
         output.status = input.overallStatus;
```

We know can remove the mapping or delete in script. But is there a any way we can comment it. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand why you want to comment the output status line.
Generally the scripting will allow // for commenting. In case of any filtering to be done then there are many features supported by MULE. Can you please elaborate your requirement so that we can help  better.

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/7-things-you-didn%E2%80%99t-know-about-datamapper/
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference#DatamapperUserGuideandReference-Examples

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just for curious I have asked ( Is there is a way).  I have already tried // it not seems to be commenting. For //MEL it is in green colour. when try to comment any line , it is not turned to be green colour.  I Know, if we dont want , can delete the script or remove the mapping. commenting is possible in Datamapper or not? thats only I want to know.